# Change boolean value for certain date range

Tags: sql-server

Hi I am working on a Hotel Reservation Project in ASP.NET. I want to make a filter so that I can search the room available by date (for example between 1 June and 5 June) and after that reserve that room .How can I do to change status of that room to "not available" for that period,so that somebody who want to reserve that room between 15 may and 30 may can do it.Status of the room is boolean value in my database.

[image]

So far i display all room with status available .But the status is set when i introduce the room in database.But I dont know how to change the status and if it is possible to set status of a room as true for a period and then false for another period

Comment: Just so that we all understand - do you want to do something like Ticketmaster does where it stops the room from being booked while someone is going through the reservation process (and maybe says something like 'you have two minutes to book this room')?

Comment: Yes something like this .I reserve a room for  A period and after that the Room is no longer available for reservation for that Period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database structure change is not required for what you're requesting, and to support a timeout feature described by MarkP3rry, you'd only need to add one field to your Reservation table: `BookingDate DATETIME`. You should be checking for availability using the reservation table. If there are no reservations against a room that overlap the supplied start and end dates, then the room is available for that period, unless the reservation has been cancelled.

To determine which rooms are available between two dates, use the following query:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM Room r LEFT JOIN Reservation v ON r.RoomID = v.RoomID
    AND NOT (@StartDate >= Date_Check_Out OR @EndDate <= Date_Check_In)
    AND v.cancel = 0
WHERE v.ReservationID IS NULL
```

This will give you all of the rooms that have no reservations against then between `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`. You can of course filter this further by room status, room type, etc. This query assumes that validation on the supplied dates has been done, i.e. that `@StartDate < @EndDate`, and that `Reservation.Check_In_Date < Reservation.Check_Out_Date`. The join will return all rooms, and only reservations that whose dates overlap the start and end dates supplied. Add `AND v.cancel = 0` to only include reservations that have not been cancelled. We then filter out the results that have any reservation data, and what is left is the available rooms between the two dates.

Comment: Thank you this is what i was looking for .Now i will try to implement it but i need do convert it to linq and dont know how but i will solve it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your database structure is incorrect. You must have the status field in Reservation Table so that you will be having the transitional history day wise.

Because in your current condition either your room will be available for all day or it will off for all day. You should make a room status table in which you should have the record of everyday status and validate your room selection on the basis of that table.

Make the Default value for the status as true. So that by default every room will be available  for booking by default.

@ianco slovak, i really feels that you must change your database structure.

Comment: I dont really understand what shoul i save in my roomstatus table?        ReservationID,RoomID,status and some Date?

Comment: Exactly, you will require all these fields in the roomstatus table, and this table must have a single entry for every room everyday.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of [Status] field is to show if room is available for now, isn't it?
If yes then you can set it as Computed - create an sql function which returns boolean (type of your Status field) and check in it that there is no reservation for the current moment.

Please read more about computed fields [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) and also about performance [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/08/03/sql-server-computed-column-persisted-and%C2%A0performance/)